# ASP.NET MVC 4 form post to url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Only just started using MVC 4 & I am not sure how to do the following.

I have a page that displays a list of blog articles '/blog', this page also contains a select list with a list of dates, selecting a date should auto post the form to a URL like '/blog/date/20-05-2015' this URL routes to a ActionResult in a controller, which returns a list of blog articles from that date.

I dont know how to get my form to automatically post to a URL like '/blog/date/20-05-2015'

ROUTE:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "blogsByDates",
            "blog/date/{date}",
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "IndexByDate" }
            );
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult IndexByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var query = from c in db.Blogs
                    where c.PublishDate >= date
                    select c;

        return View("Index", query.ToList());
    }
```

VIEW (PARTIAL)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
  { 
<select name="ddlMonth" id="ddlMonth">
<option value="01-06-2012">June 2012</option>
<option value="01-05-2012">May 2012</option> 
</select> 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use jQuery or something to change the ACTION attribute of your form. There's no other way to change the destination a form posts to. Though why you're using a form when you're not sending any special data to the server. Just make it a list of clickable links.